# Error in query. Missing parenthesis

Tags: mysql, sql, exception

I have the following SQL query which is for

```
SELECT ac.Source_and, 
    ac.Location_spending, 
    ac.type, 
    Sum( ac.balance ) - 
        coalesce( (SELECT Sum( ac.balance ) 
                   FROM Account ac cost
                   WHERE (ac.type = 0)
                   and (cost.Creditor_Account = income.Location_spending)
                   GROUP BY ac.Source , ac.Creditor_Account, ac.type)
                ,0)     
FROM Account ac income
WHERE ac.type = 1
GROUP BY ac.Source_and , ac.Location_spending, ac.type
```

but it is returning the following exception:

> [88, 88] The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.
>   [88, 88] The right parenthesis is missing from the COALESCE expression.
>   [217, 315] The query contains a malformed ending.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: I have edited your post, replace the part which says: `<!-- fill in here what the query is for -->` with what the query is for.

Comment: `FROM Account ac income` is invalid syntax.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (SQL server, MySQL, ...)

Comment: 'FROM Account ac cost' is also bad syntax. Every table can have one alias.

Comment: i want use it in java persistence(jpql)

Comment: I think instead of ac suppose to be AS

Comment: select ac.balance , ac.Location_spending, ac.Source_and ,ac.Creditor_Account ,ac.Source ,ac.date from Account ac

Comment: ac is correct.see my exception